# Is there a way to only return a PART of a compound primary key?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL table with a compound key, ID (int, autogenerated) and TaxpayerID (varchar, user enters it). When the user registers, they enter a taxpayer ID & the taxpayer ID combined with the ID make a Primary Key.

Normally after entering a record, I'd return used @@Identity and return it to a Integer variable in my .NET application. However, it seems to be failing, I think because it is a compound key.

Is there a way to only return a PART of a compound primary key? (in this case, just the ID field)

Comment: They are 2 distinct columns. ID is an int, TaxpayerID is a varchar. DBA set them up as a composite key. But I only need the one (ID) returned after record is inserted.

Comment: How do you know that "it seems to be failing"?  What do you see that indicates a problem?

Comment: When I run it in Query Analyzer is does seem to return the ID. However, when it gets back to .NET, it is failing in its cast to an integer variable. I checked 4 times to make sure my variables were int and this column is int.

Answer (score 2):

Suggest return [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx). That will return the last `IDENTITY` value created in your scope. I'd suggest to prefer `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` because

> SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY return the last identity values that are generated in any table in the current session. However, SCOPE_IDENTITY returns values inserted only within the current scope; @@IDENTITY is not limited to a specific scope.

In your case, it's a bit muddled with the compound, but if you're looking for the auto-incremented `IDENTITY` field, this will do it for you. The PK on the table doesn't matter. If there's a field marked with `IDENTITY`, and you want it returned, use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` immediately after the `INSERT`.

Comment: But wouldn't that return the total key (ID + TaxpayerID) as opposed to just the ID part of the key.

Comment: @donde: no, that'll return the `IDENTITY` value last inserted.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused what the identity is. These columns are both designated in the table as being part of the Primary Key. Wouldn't that make them BOTH the identity? Or is Identity defined by something else?

Comment: @donde: NO! The "IDENTITY" column is the one that's defined as such - as datatype INT IDENTITY. There can only ever be one per table. The Primary Key is one thing - but that's totally separate from the automatically generated IDENTITY column value - that's what SCOPE_IDENTITY() return (this **is** only part of your PK)